# Data Structure : Stack

Tags: c, stack

```
1.theStack.push(1);
2.theStack.push(2);
3.theStack.push(3);
4.theStack.push(theStack.pop()); 
5.theStack.push(theStack.pop() +theStack.pop()); 
6.theStack.push(6); 
7.theStack.push(7); 
8.theStack.push(theStack.pop() * theStack.pop());
```

When first 3 lines are executed output will be

```
|3|
|2|
|1|
```

I have a problem understanding above mentioned lines. Could anyone please explain above line. What happens with 4th-8th lines?

Comment: They get lost inside the code you did not post. Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Are you sure that's `popO` and not `pop()`? (And if you're not sure...) Similarly with the `:`.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Is this C? I don't think so. Post a complete example and adjust language tag please...

Comment: It could be C, I suppose, if these are function pointers inside a `struct`, but of course it is more likely to be C++ (or Java, or JavaScript, or...)

Comment: I guess I missed the *scope resolution operator* in the latest C11 standard... (or the `':'` could be a typo)

Comment: It is C, Please provide MCVE

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `pop0` is a typo and it's supposed to be a call to `pop()`, it removes the last element you pushed to the stack and returns it. Let's follow the program:

```
theStack.push(1);
// 1 is pushed to the stack. The stack now contains [1]

theStack.push(2);
// 2 is pushed to the stack. The stack now contains [2, 1]

theStack.push(3);
// 3 is pushed to the stack. The stack now contains [3, 2, 1]

theStack.push(theStack.pop()); 
// 3 is popped, and then pushed back in, so the stack still contains [3, 2, 1]

theStack.push(theStack.pop() + theStack.pop()); 
// 3 and 2 are popped, added, and pushed back in, so the stack now contains 
// [5, 1]

theStack.push(6); 
// 6 is pushed to the stack. The stack now contains [6, 5, 1]

theStack.push(7); 
// 7 is pushed to the stack. The stack now contains [7, 6, 5, 1]

theStack.push(theStack.pop() * theStack.pop());
// 7 and 6 are popped, multiplied, and pushed back in, so the stack now contains
// [42, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik 
    theStack.push(theStack.pop() + theStack.pop()); 
    // 3 and 2 are popped, added, and pushed back in, so the stack now 
    contains 
    // [5, 1] (how did you get the value 5)

Comment: @Eranka 3+2 = 5 :-)